# In Spark AR, how can I have an object disappear below a target tracker?

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I have an object, say a building, that I want to "rise" out of the ground (target tracker in this instance).

The issue is that Spark still shows objects on your phone even when they're below the tracker, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the following steps:

1. Add a plane in your target tracking property, make sure it is at the top of all the objects in the target tracking property
   [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaDKg.png)
2. place the plane over your target so it fully covers it from the camera. Also make sure to put it as close to the target as possible, so it seems that the object comes through the target.
   [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi1xW.png)
3. Add a material to the plane
4. under render options, give the material 0% opacity

It now looks like it comes out of the target:
[(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgaVI.png)